# Force method invocation in builder method

Tags: android, picasso, android-lint

I have created a Builder class which initializes the Picasso library object in variety of ways, properties like `gravity`, `resize(x,y)` etc.

In one particular case, if `isCenterCropGravity(int gravity)` is called. The gravity is operational if the resize method is also called while creating the object.

In order to achieve so, I want to create a custom lint check, within which, if the `centerCropGravity()` method is called before `resize()` method, a lint error message warning should be displayed, now I've never written custom lint check and any available resource on the internet is not remotely related to the solution i want to achieve.

Comment: It is a quite complicated lint check. One approach you can try is to visit `UCallExpression`s and `UQualifiedReferenceExpression`s, checking their `receiver`s - figuring out the call chain.